# Use selected item in dropdown to show item in display in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps

I got a Dropdown Menu, where you can select one title, which belongs to an item of a sharepoint list.
Now what I want to do is, I want to display some fields of this list item. Therefore I am using "Display".

But how can I set the Item up?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by `"...I am using "Display"`, but the way you access other columns in the selected Sharepoint record is:

- **Given**:

  - Sharepoint list named `employees`
  - Dropdown control named `Dropdown2`
- Set `Dropdown2.Items` property to `employees`
- Select a column to display to user
- Add a Label control
- Set its Text property to `Dropdown2.Selected.columnName`
- Where `columnName` is the other column you'd like to display to user based on their selection

[image]